# Transferring data from SD Card to Internal Memory and vice versa

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card

I have a Smartphone; Sony XPERIA SP with Android 4.3 (updated). While recently updating the apps on my phone, it told me that the Internal Memory was close to full. So I inserted a 2 GB microSD Card (which I found on my drawer by luck) after which my phone prompted a notification to transfer some data to the SD Card. I clicked on the notification and the data got automatically transferred! (I had to select just a few things) After few days someone gifted me a 32 GB microSD Card and so I was thinking of replacing it with my current card. But then to do so I need to transfer the data from my current SD Card to the phone again and then re transfer the data back again to the new SD Card. But how am I suppose to transfer data to the phone again? I found no option to do that. Also is there any other way to replace the new card with the existing one so that no files get deleted or misplaced?

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way that you can do this. However if you really want to do it, you will have to connect both memory cards to computer and transfer the files manually by selecting all. And if you don't have computer you cant do by app, [es explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) which is freely available in play store this transfer by first placing the files in your sd card and then insert the new sd card and if the system prompts you about the storage full, then you have what you want.

Comment: I have a Laptop!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I got the answer. What I did is just I plugged the SD Card into an adapter and inserted in my laptop and copied all the files and folders into a folder on my laptop. Then I plugged the other card into the laptop and transferred all the files into it. And it is working without any errors.